# ¿Como agregar un atributo a una etiqueta html ya existente con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo agregar un `onkeypress` a un `input` desde `javaScript`?.

Mi código es el siguiente, la función **soloNumero** funciona, ya la probé.

```
<form action="" id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Solo números" id="btn">

</form>

$("#btn").addEventListener("click", function(){

        var input = document.getElementById("btn")

        input.setAttribute("onkeypress", "return soloNumero(event)");
        input.setAttribute("onpaste", "return false");

        $("#form").appendChild(input)           
    })
    function $(selector){
        return document.querySelector(selector)
    }
```

Comment: Explicame un poco mejor, probe tu codigo y si agrega onkeypress y onpaste al input, cual es el problema que tienes

Answer (score 1):

### Adjuntar Eventos Dinámicos

Para adjuntar un evento a un elemento **html** de manera dinámica (a una pagina en ejecución) podemos hacerlo con ***jQuery*** usando el comando [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/), también se puede hacer con ***javaScript*** usando el comando [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Partiendo de tu código, te dejo un ejemplo funcional de como hacerlo con ***jQuery***:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
 $("#btn").on({
  keypress: soloNumeros,
  paste: function(e) { return console.info("onPaste in: "+e.target.id); }
 });
})
function soloNumeros(e) {
 console.info("onKeypress in: "+e.target.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Solo números" id="btn">
</form>
```

Aquí te dejo otro ejemplo donde solo permite **ingresar números**, ademas incluye un `input` donde te muestro como usar ***expresiones regulares*** con **html5**

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
 $("#btn").on({
  keydown: soloNumeros,
  paste: function(e) { return false; }
 });
})
function soloNumeros(e) {
 return (e.key.length != 1 || 1+e.key.search(/^[0-9]/)) ? true : false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Solo números" id="btn">

 <!-- ingresar solo números usando expresiones regulares en html5 
      la validacion se ejecuta cuando pulsas el boton "submit"-->
 <input type="text" placeholder="Solo números" pattern="^[0-9]*" title="debe ingresar solo numeros">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Espero te ayude el ejemplo ;))...

Answer (score 0):

Probé tu código y si agrega `onkeypress` y `onpaste` al `input`

Prueba borrar la linea:

```
$("#form").appendChild(input)
```

Para que te permita escribir en el `input` luego de haber agregado los atributos.

Te quedaría algo así:

```
$("#btn").addEventListener("click", function(){

        var input = document.getElementById("btn")

        input.setAttribute("onkeypress", "soloNumero(event)");
        input.setAttribute("onpaste", "return false");

    })
    function $(selector){
        return document.querySelector(selector)
    }
```